# GParted can't drag and drop partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I just can't drag and drop a partition to the left to increase its size.

I have 2 partitions:

- 1 unallocated 118Go
- 2 ext4 120 Go

[image]

And I want to extend the ext2 to all space but can't extend it by drag and drop:
[image]

What can I do?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I couldn't do it because it was mounted! I thought it's was not mounted because the USB was disappearing from my Gnome File Manager when Gparted was started and the USB drive selected.

I unmounted it, and then could do it!

[image]

Comment: You need to boot into a live environment to do this. The partition you are working on appears to be locked

Comment: It's a USB drive, it should not be locked! And when I open GParted and select this USB key, it get unmounted.

Comment: Sorry, the drive was actually mounted and this why I couldn't do it!

Comment: @karel I just didn't notice that my USB drive was not unmounted whereas it disappeared from the Gnome file manager. I add to unmount it from Gparted before.